# continuity on a cartesian rectangle

Tags: analysis

Let $H = [a,b] \times [c,d]$ be a rectangle and let $f : H \rightarrow R$ be continuous. Then the book says that for each $y$ element of $[c,d]$, $f(.,y)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. What does that actually mean?
Can I also say that for each element $x$ of $[a,b]$, $f(x,.)$ is continuous on $[c,d]$?

Comment: It means that the function $\phi(x) = f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. And yes, the same applies to the $y$ functions.

Comment: Thanks. Now, like partial derivative, do we keep the x constant to find partial integration on [c,d] and likewise, keep y constant to find partial integration on [a,b]?

Comment: Yes, if you are integrating with respect to $y$ and $x$ respectively...

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(x) =  f(x,y_0)$ is a function of on one variable $g\colon [a,b]\to R$. The book is saying that this function is continuous.

And, yes, also the function $h(y) = f(x_0,y)$ is continuous.